# no app to perform this action android email

Tags: java, android, email, email-client

There are plenty of people with this issue but none of their solution apply on mine, I try to change the Type from rfc822 to plaintext, open the email in my emulator and set an account, use intent action_sendto  Uri.parse"mailto:", action send.

Do I need to install something in the emulator or this really work for a real phone?

```
send  =(Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);

send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"myemail@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "HEY");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "example@gmail.com");
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(email.this, "Sorry, no email client found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working,

Use this code to send E-mail

```
 publicvoid sendEmail() {
      Log.i("Send email", "");
      String[] TO = {""};       // Array of email address whom you want to send email
      String[] CC = {""};       // Array of email address whom you want to keep in CC
      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);    // E-mail Addresss
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");  // Email Subject
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");  // your E-mail body

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      }
      catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

**For more info**

**Intent Object** - Action to send Email You will use ACTION_SEND action to launch an email client installed on your Android device. Following is simple syntax to create an intent with ACTION_SEND action

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

**Intent Object** - Data/Type to send Email To send an email you need to specify `mailto:` as URI using setData() method and data type will be to `text/plain` using `setType()` method as follows −

```
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

**Intent Object - Extra to send Email**

```
EXTRA_BCC
```

A String[] holding e-mail addresses that should be blind carbon copied.

```
EXTRA_CC
```

A String[] holding e-mail addresses that should be carbon copied.

```
EXTRA_EMAIL
```

A String[] holding e-mail addresses that should be delivered to.

```
EXTRA_HTML_TEXT
```

A constant String that is associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply an alternative to EXTRA_TEXT as HTML formatted text.

```
EXTRA_SUBJECT
```

A constant string holding the desired subject line of a message.

```
EXTRA_TEXT
```

A constant CharSequence that is associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the literal data to be sent.

```
EXTRA_TITLE
```

A CharSequence dialog title to provide to the user when used with a ACTION_CHOOSER.